# RQGIS3 : AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'RQGIS3'

Tags: qgis-3, attributeerror

I am trying to use the RQGIS3 package to access QGIS3 functions from R, and although briefly I had things working (mostly), running the following code:

```
library(RQGIS3)
qgis_env <- set_env("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.4")
qgis_session_info(qgis_env=qgis_env)</code>
```

now produces the following error:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'RQGIS3'
```

I'm not sure what changed. Another [post](https://github.com/r-spatial/RQGIS/issues/115) suggested that the order in which packages were loaded determined whether this error cropped up, but in my case, I have not even loaded any other packages. I am pretty new at using RQGIS(3), and know next to nothing about Python.

I am using QGIS 3.4.7, and R 3.5.0 (I will get out IT staff to upgrade R next week to see if that fixes things).

Any thoughts what else might be going on here?

Comment: Get your IT staff to update QGIS to a supported build, as well. Either 3.4.15-1 LTS (about to be deprecated) or 3.10.2-2.

Comment: I have not had a chance yet to update QGIS, but I got R updated to 3.6.1 (the latest approved version for me). But I can't install RQGIS3 on it because `remotes:::install.github()` throws an error because `reticulate` expects R 3.6.2, even though I specify `R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS="true"` as suggested at <https://github.com/r-lib/remotes#environment-variables>. I'll report back when I get this resolved.

Comment: I did `Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=TRUE)` and then QGIS3 installed just fine (mostly). There were some warnings that links to SpatialPointsDataframes (Polygons, Lines) did not exist and were being treated as a topic.
I also updated QGIS to 3.4.11 (the latest approved version in our organization) and it made no difference.
My operating system is WIndows 10. I have a laptop with Linux Mint, and QGIS 3.4.13, and things seem to work fine over there.

Comment: One other note: The above error does not appear when I invoke `native:zonalhistogram` in RStudio as opposed to RGui, and it seems to produce the correct results. But in RStudio a bunch of other warnings appear (Deprecation warnings about invalid escape sequence, and about `importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc'`), and there is a warning about `ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.`

Comment: I can only strongly recommend you use a supported version to test against, again. I'll see if I can replicate this on a personal machine with W10/QGIS 3.10.2-2

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that, but approval of software is slow here, so it might be awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap this up over a year later. I never did resolve this issue, even after I updated to QGIS 3.16. However, in the meantime, I read that `RQGIS3` is no longer maintained, and it's use is discouraged. Instead, there is now a command line executable called `qgis_process` in QGIS (3.14 and later), and a corresponding R package called `qgisprocess` (read about it [here](https://github.com/paleolimbot/qgisprocess)) that does much of what `RQGIS3` did, and it does not rely on Python. I've tried it, and it did what I wanted, and it has rendered moot the issue I described above.